# how to use celebA dataset with DCGAN

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, kaggle

I am trying the DCGAN tutorial of Tensorflow

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan

At the bottom of the page, it said I can try this model with celebA dataset on kaggle, however, after trying some method, I still can't find a correct way to import the dataset.

I know the dataset is imported from here
`(train_images, train_labels), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()`

but I can't find a way to modify it.

Comment: You can use the Kaggle API to access the dataset from Kaggle.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at [Keras sample](https://keras.io/examples/generative/dcgan_overriding_train_step/) will help.

(I know it is late but might be useful for next visitor)